# Calculating difference in "APY" between assets

Tags: united-states, income-tax, interest-rate, state-income-tax, fixed-income

Treasuries are not taxed at state and local level.
Munis are not taxed at any level at times.

What formula is used to compare APY between different investment assets, given:

- CD, Treasuries, Munis at 10%.
- Effective tax rate 12%.
- Effective state/local tax rate 3%.

What is "true" APY between three assets given tax-free status of treasuries and munis at a given effective tax rate?

Answer (score 2):

APY does not consider taxes since everyone's tax situation is different. If you want an *after-tax* APY for taxable investments, just multiply the APY by `(1-T)` where `T` is your *marginal* (not effective) tax rate.

You use marginal rate because that's how much *additional* tax you'll pay if you choose to invest in taxable securities.

Comment: Thank you for the marginal explanation. Took a bit but I understand now the "additional" tax part.